# If operators do not commute they cannot have a complete set of eigenfunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, commutator

$\def\ket#1{|#1\rangle}$

I am trying to show a simple proof of,

> If operators do not commute they cannot have a complete set of eigenfunctions.

**start**

Let $[\hat P, \hat Q]=0$, or $\hat P \text{ and } \hat Q$ commute.

Then $\hat P \hat Q\ket\psi = q_n\hat P\ket\psi$, the eigenvalues of the observables $\hat P$ are just a scalar multiple away from the values of $\hat Q$.

If $[\hat P, \hat Q]\neq0$, then the values of $\hat P$ dont have any linear transformation to get the values of $\hat Q$. Therefore, their values are linearly independent or orthogonal.

**end**

Is this convincing or am I skipping something?

Comment: Also if someone could help me with the bra-ket syntax I would appriciate it. \ket{} did not work.

Comment: \ket{} requires a special Latex package. Use \rangle and \langle.

Comment: what values of $P$ are you talking about?  Also, you are not considering multiple occurrences of the same eigenvalue.  *The eigenvalues of P are just a scalar multiple away from the values of Q* is meaningless since P and Q need not have the same spectrum or two numbers are always a multiple away one from the other,

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I was thinking of the eighenvalues, $p_n$ from $\hat P | \psi \rangle=p_n | \psi \rangle$. In releation to the same value thing: I would think that degegenate cases for $\hat P$ would also be degenrate under $\hat Q$. But, I might be deeply confused. Could you elaborate on what you mean by, "$P$ and $Q$ need not have the same spectrum...?"

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because check-my-work questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by assuming that $\hat P$ and $\hat Q$ have a common set of eigenfunctions $f_n$ such that the set $\{f_n\}$ is complete (ie any function in Hilbert space can be represented by a linear combination):

$$ f = \sum c_n f_n $$

So we have (1) $\hat P f_n = \lambda_n f_n$ and (2) $\hat Q f_n = \nu_n f_n$. Consider:

$$ [\hat P, \hat Q]f = (\hat P \hat Q - \hat Q \hat P)f = (\hat P \hat Q - \hat Q \hat P) \sum c_n f_n 
\\ = \hat P \left(\sum c_n \nu_n f_n \right) - \hat Q \left(\sum c_n \lambda_n f_n \right) 
\\ = \left(\sum c_n \nu_n \lambda_n f_n \right) - \left(\sum c_n \lambda_n\nu_n f_n \right) = 0$$

Where in the last two steps we have used (1) and (2) which was assumed. This then holds for any $f$ since we can represent it using the complete basis formed by the eigenfunctions so we conclude that $[\hat P, \hat Q] = 0$ must hold under these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$ share a common set of eigenfunctions $\textbf{x}$, such that:

$$\textbf{Ax} = a\textbf{x},$$
and
$$\textbf{Bx} = b\textbf{x}.$$
Thus,
$$\textbf{ABx} = ab\textbf{x}, $$
and
$$\textbf{BAx} = ba\textbf{x}$$
which implies

$$[\textbf{A},\textbf{B}] = 0.$$

Therefore (by *modus tollens*), if $[\textbf{A},\textbf{B}] \neq 0,$ then $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$ do not share a common set of eigenfunctions.